# Reduce memory setting image to imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I am showing a series of questions to the user. In each question I set drawables to 6 imageviews. The only problem is the ram usage goes up about 60MB ever time I go to the next screen.

I dont understand why this is happening because I am just replacing the picture with a different one? After about 5 screens the app crashing because of failed memory allocation. How would I release this memory of the screen before it so It doesnt build up.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageButton a1;
    ImageButton a2;
    ImageButton a3;
    ImageButton a4;
    Intent result;
    String correctOrWrong = "";
    int question;
    int amountOfC = 0;
    int numCorrect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        ImageView qMain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qMain);
        a1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
        a2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
        a3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a3);
        a4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a4);
        ImageView qTitle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qTitle);


        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nextQ(1);
            }
        });

        a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nextQ(2);
            }
        });

        a3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nextQ(3);
            }
        });

        a4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nextQ(4);
            }
        });

        Intent qGet = getIntent();
        question = qGet.getIntExtra("QNUMBER", 1);
        numCorrect = qGet.getIntExtra("NUMCORRECT", 1);

        Log.d("lel", String.valueOf(question));

        if (question == 1) {
            qMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q1);
            a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a13);
            a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a12);
            a3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a11);
            a4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ca1);
            qTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q1t);

        } else if (question == 2) {
            qMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q2);
            a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q23);
            a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q2a);
            a3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q22);
            a4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q21);
            qTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q2t);
        } else if (question == 3) {
            qMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q3);
            a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q31);
            a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q32);
            a3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q33);
            a4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q3a);
            qTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q3t);
        } else if (question == 4) {
            qMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q4);
            a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q4a);
            a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q43);
            a3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q42);
            a4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q41);
            qTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q4t);
        } else if (question == 5) {
            qMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q5);
            a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q53);
            a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q5a);
            a3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q52);
            a4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q51);
            qTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q5t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't handle image memory/caching yourself, instead use a library such as glide  - https://github.com/bumptech/glide

or

try clearing the imageview onDestroy() of the acitvity

```
a1.setImageDrawable(null);
a2.setImageDrawable(null);
a3.setImageDrawable(null);
a4.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call recycle() for every bitmap after you used them like below :

```
a1.setImageDrawable(null);
a2.setImageDrawable(null);
a3.setImageDrawable(null);
a4.setImageDrawable(null);
a1.recycle();
a2.recycle();
a3.recycle();
a4.recycle();
```